# Programmatically get log cat data

Tags: android, android-logcat

i want to get logcat data programmatically i used the below code

```
 StringBuilder debuglog=new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                debuglog.append(line);
                debuglog.append("\r\n");
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Above code is working fine

This line `"logcat -d`" shows -d,-w,-i messages

But,my problem is i want to show -e messages

Comment: Does not work anymore with Android 4.1 :-(

Answer (score 4):

To get only ERROR use this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d *:E");
```